Is it possible to update an existing (ECDSA) account on Hedera to use Multisig & Threshold Keys for Signing?
I have an existing ECDSA Hedera account I've created. I would now like to be able to update this account to be a Multisig account (using three other keys) with a threshold of 3/3 (so all keys have to sign).
Our current code (taken from here), where privateKey(n) are derived from ECDSA DER-encoded Private Keys, editAccount represents the account being changed, and editKey is the private key for the editAccount:
// Create a `KeyList` that represents a 3 of 3 multisig threshold
const multisigPublicKeys = [(await privateKey1).publicKey, (await privateKey2).publicKey, (await privateKey3).publicKey];
const multisigKeyList = new KeyList(multisigPublicKeys, 3);

//Log Keys (**Only visual output at this stage**)
console.log('These are your new credentials...');
console.log('Multisig Keylist ' + multisigKeyList.toString());

//Create the transaction to update the key on the account
const transaction = await new AccountUpdateTransaction()
    .setAccountId(editAccount)
    .setKey(multisigKeyList)
    .freezeWith(client);

//Sign the transaction with the old key and new key(s)
const SignedByOriginalTx = await transaction.sign(editKey);
const SignedByFirstTx = await SignedByOriginalTx.sign(privateKey1);
const SignedBySecondTx = await SignedByFirstTx.sign(privateKey2);
const SignedByThirdTx = await SignedBySecondTx.sign(privateKey3);

//Sign the transaction with the client operator private key and submit to a Hedera network
const txResponse = await SignedByThirdTx.execute(client);

I'm seeing the following error response:
const publicKeyData = publicKey.toBytesRaw();
                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBytesRaw')


Having explored the Hedera JS SDK code I spotted this comment:
// note: this omits the DER prefix on purpose because Hedera doesn't
// support that in the protobuf. this means that we would fail
// to re-inflate [this._signerPublicKeys] during [fromBytes] if we used DER
// prefixes here
const publicKeyHex = hex.encode(publicKeyData);

I then tried to rebuild the ECDSA private keys using their HEX-encoded version (i.e. 0x....) and this allowed the Account Update Transaction to proceed successfully.
// Add Keys for Multisig (based on 3 accounts)
const privateKey1 = PrivateKey.fromStringECDSA('<Insert HEX-encoded Private Key String Here>');
const privateKey2 = PrivateKey.fromStringECDSA('<Insert HEX-encoded Private Key String Here>');
const privateKey3 = PrivateKey.fromStringECDSA('<Insert HEX-encoded Private Key String Here>');


I see that now you're using PrivateKey.fromStringECDSA to construct your private keys: https://github.com/woodwardmatt/hashgraph-tools/blob/660628d2/account_key_to_threshold_key.js#L22 ... What were you using before when you encountered TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBytesRaw')?

@bguiz one way or another I was trying similar to PrivateKey.fromStringDer then using the DER-Encoded key value.

Hmm interesting - was there any difference between a DER encoded ECDSA private key and a DER encoded EdDSA key?

Weirdly the public keys were the same values (shown in the log of the Keylist), but when it got to executing the transaction that's when the error reared its head.

Hmm in that case I reckon the issue is probably in the SDK implementation, probably down to that specific comment that you've found in the implementation. This might indicate an edge-case bug in the SDK implementation, worth investigating. Could you please file an issue on this on the  hedera-sdk-js repo pls? (citing this S/O q&a)
